# How to raise Exception in HSQLDB procedure or function

Tags: exception, hsqldb

What I want to do is just raise a exception in HSQL 2.0.

As in Oracle we can use :
....
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
raise_application_error(XXX)
....

After read HSQL official documentation and tried what I can imagine , I still didn't get a clue.

Is there anybody can give a suggestion ? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the SIGNAL statement in the Guide:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_psm_exceptions

Example:

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000';
```

HSQLDB follows the SQL Standard PSM syntax for procedures and functions. This syntax is also followed by DB2, therefore many DB2 examples can be used with HSQLDB.

Comment: What isn't mentioned in the guide, and is only hinted at in the answer is that the code needs to be 5 characters.  See also https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Structured_Query_Language/SQLSTATE